# How do you expand an existing patio while retaining look, structure & level?

Tags: brick, patio

I have an existing Brick patio that was put in sometime around the time of house construction. There is a small attached garden that has a tree which has since died and I am thinking of expanding the patio to take over that section of the garden (primarily as a place to keep my Grill).

Without a lot of trial-and-error how do I expand into the garden and keep it at the same level as my existing patio?

Answer (score 1):

Use a level, and compact the base to the correct level so that when bricks are placed on it the resulting surface will be level. Choice of levels ranges from surveyor's total station on down to water in a clear hose. The aim is the same in all cases. Note that the patio may not really be "level" - it should have a very slight slope away from the house to aid in directing surface runoff, as should the new section.

Your title but not the body of your question mentioned retaining the look - that may be the hardest part - finding brick to match old brick is a challenge, particularly if your home is relatively old. You may be able to find a construction materials salvage yard with old brick.

As for maintaining the structure, dig down and see how the old one is built, and match that.

Comment: Matching the brick color and texture is almost certainly impossible unless there are other bricks available from the neighborhood.  After installing the nearest physical match, power washing it all might help make it look the same.

Comment: Another approach might be to deliberately design in a color/texture change -- something that looks intentional often beats something that looks like you were trying to match and got it wrong. Make it two different outdoor "rooms", or a patterned surround, or something like that... (I periodically consider changing the near-ground-level deck that came with my house to a patio. I'd change it to a raised deck instead, but it wouldn't be raised enough for the space underneath to be useful, darn it.)

Comment: Suggestion: buy new bricks that nearly match, co-ordinate, or harmonize when randomly mixed with your old bricks. Remove from your existing patio almost enough bricks to make your extension, and replace them with the new bricks. (The fraction of bricks removed should match the ratio of the extension area to the existing patio area.) Build the extension from the mixture of removed and new bricks.